# How to fit canvas to the actual image?

Tags: crop, canvas, krita

I have an image which has a lot of transparency around it and I need the canvas to automatically fit the image. Currently I am doing this by hand with the crop tool. Is there any *fit canvas to image* function in Krita?

Comment: It's entirely possible that it doesn't have this functionality, given that it is a painting / drawing application.

Comment: @Joonas, I fail to understand.  I believe that it would be possible to have an automated crop feature which crops out all surrounding transparent pixels until it hits a colors pixel, and then resize the canvas to the cropped area.

Comment: I mean I don't know if it does have that. It's just that this is an application where brushing stuff on the canvas is the main thing. It would not surprise me if it didn't have it. Like, I'm going to paint this scenery... and then I'll be super artistic and crop it mathematically/automatically. That was just my first thought when I saw this question. Again, I've not used enough of it to know if it has that or not.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that in Image > Trim image to current Layer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to trim the surrounding pixels that are outside the canvas boundaries there is **Trim to Image size** in the image menu.

This will crop out all the pixels on all layers that are outside the canvas boundary.